# Actualizar RecyclerView al modificar un registro y volver atrás

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy intentando marcar como favoritos algunos registros mostrados en un RecyclerView. Lo mismo que hace el programa Gmail de Google.

Marco los favoritos con un ToggleButton, almaceno en base de datos y funciona cuando lo hago directamante en el RecyclerView, este mantiene los valores reales (el problema de perderlos al hacer scroll ya lo resolví).

El problema es al ver el detalle del registro y modificarlo. La base de datos actualiza correctamente pero al dar al boton atrás el RecyclerView no se actualiza, mantiene la vista con los valores antiguos. Si aplico un filtro si se visualiza correctamente.

Supongo que debería decir que se actualizaran los valores en onResume() pero no se como decirle que refresque la vista.

Este es mi método onCreateView

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view;
     if (ListaRecetas.getDataList(col,query, getContext()).size()>0){
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receta_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));


        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecetaRecyclerViewAdapter(
                ListaRecetas.getDataList(col,query, getContext()), mListener,context));

    }
     }else{
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sin_registros, container, false);
     }
    return view;
}




 public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();

}
```

¿Como puedo hacer desde onResume() que se actualice?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que podes hacer es volver a declarar el adaptador dentro de `onResume()`

```
 public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();

  recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecetaRecyclerViewAdapter(
                ListaRecetas.getDataList(col,query, getContext()), mListener,context));

}
```

hay ciertas formas como el `notifyDataSetChanged()` que funciona con recycler, pero la mejor forma es volver a rellenar el `Adapter`  tambien podes hacer `mRecyclerView.invalidate();` para volver a rellenar el recycler, pero con solo volver a setear el `Adaptador` deberia bastar

Comment: Funciona bien el refrescar el adapter.. El problema es que elimino registros y si se eliminan todos da error. Verificando que no sea 0 funciona bien hasta el último que no puedo quitar. Cuando no hay registros quiero que aparezca un mensaje como el que se muestra en onCreateView() He probado con `fragmentTransaction.remove(this).commit();`  e intentando que se cargue otra vez el fragment. Tambien he intentado añadir y sacar del backStack para ver si conseguía que se ejecutara onCreateView(). Alguna idea?